# Закрыть другое приложение c#, работающее в фоновом режиме

Tags: c#

Если работает два софта (софт1 и софт2) то какой командой, выполняемой софтом2) я могу остановить работу софта1 ?
как запустить софт я знаю, а если его выключить...

Comment: @Nikita, вопрос с другого сайта SE не является основой для дубликата..

Comment: @Nikita такие комментарии размещаются автоматически при отдаче голоса за закрытие (на что у вас пока нет репутации). Не заморачивайтесь с имитацией их вручную. И vp_arth прав, задубликатить вопрос на другой сайт невозможно, и на то есть веские причины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете завершить процесc по его имени:

```
try
{
    Process [] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("utorrent");
    proc[0].Kill();
}
```